# How to inject an Azure Key Vault password into a mysql script during pipeline runtime

Tags: mysql, bash, sed, azure-devops

Hello I am trying to inject a password from keyvault using sed in an Azure DevOps pipeline

I am successful in injecting pipeline variables but when I like a global variable containing the key from keyvault my password won't get changed.

What is the best way to change/add a password in an existing script file?
The instruction I used was

```
sed -i 's|##secret##|$(mysqladmin-password)|g'   $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_integrationDB/integrationDB/DDL_scripts/IntegDB_DDL.sql
```

`##secret##` is a placeholder value in the mysql script
I tried the above with a local variable and it works

Comment: shouldn't it be `s/xxx/yyy/g`? also, for the variable you should just use `$MYSQLADMIN-PASSWORD` if this is in the script file, if you pass this inline - it should work

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing should caused by the [special](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group) usage of key vault secret variable:

> However, secret variables (encrypted variables and key vault
>   variables) cannot be accessed directly in scripts - instead they must
>   be passed as arguments to a task.

As 4c74356b41 said in comment, based on this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) mentioned, what about using environment variable in your script?

1) Firstly, ensure the configuration of Azure key vault connected into azure devops pipeline is correct. Here you can refer to this [blog](https://zimmergren.net/using-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-azure-devops-pipeline/).

2) If all above is available, then go **Environment Variables** and configure the environment variable:

[image]

3) Now, try with calling your variable with `$env:PASSWORD` in your script.